# CakePHP how to get value from another table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have  a problem that I have 3 tables:
Users,
Images (user_id),
Comments (user_id, image_id),

Now from Image view I want to "translate" user_id from table Comment. How to do it? 
I was trying to create helper but the view helper does not see the $this->tableName variable or I had an error there.
I know that I have access to Comment table in the Image view ($image['Comment']) so I have the user_id which I want to convert to the username but how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but you may find that altering [model recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive) will make this available. Debug the $image array in your view to make sure:

```
<?php debug($image) ?>
```

Comment: Wow Nice function, but I do not have access to the User table from the Comment table :/ I need to do something like $this->User->find($user_id); but in view or in helper, but I have no idea how to do it as I am really fresh in CakePHP :/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the containable behaviour. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

When you search for comments do it something like this

```
$this->Comment->find('all',array('contain'=>'User'));
```

That will return your comments along with the user details that you need. Pass this information into your view, rather than trying to retrieve it in your view.

Comment: Yes, but I have to have access to it from Image view :/ So I get data like this:  
function view($id = null) {
if (!$id) {
 $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid image', true));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
$this->set('image', $this->Image->read(null, $id));
}
And it has hasMany relation with comments and I have access to comments - it do it automaticaly. But I can not find solution how now having the user_id translate it to the username :/

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to the User and Comment table. I prefer `pr($images);` might be easier to read but, user's data should be in there.

```
foreach ($images as $image){
    pr($image['User']['fname']);
}
```